# Changing an image randomly

Tags: image, random

Guys I would like to change the image when a person enters the site, for example, have a static block that loads an image and when a person enters or gives an F5 I would like to change the name of the image in order to always have a new image. The code below is within the home:

```
<Div class = "grid12-4 banner"> <img src = "{{url =" / banners / image_1.jpg "}}" alt = "" /> <br/> </ div>
```

I want to change this name as a random variable from 1 to 10, so could have 10 different images:

```
image_ [number-Random] .jpg
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: what's `average` here in image src ?

Comment: Code [class="grid12-4 banner"><img src="{{media url="/banners/imagem_1.jpg"}}"]

Comment: Updated the answer, does it helps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your static block content as

```
<div class = "grid12-4 banner"><img src = "{{media url="/banners/RANDOM_IMAGE_NAME"}}" alt = ""/><br/></div>
```

Then Do replace `RANDOM_IMAGE_NAME` with random image names like:

```
<?php 
echo str_replace("RANDOM_IMAGE_NAME", "image_".rand(1,10).".jpg", $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('test-block')->toHtml() ); 
?>
```

**Note**: Replace `STATIC_BLOCK_ID_HERE` with name of your static block

**UPDATE:** Change image by `javascript`

Add this Content to your Homepage. Image will be replaced by `javascript` now

```
<div class = "grid12-4 banner" id="random_image"><img src = "{{media url="/banners/RANDOM_IMAGE_NAME"}}" alt = ""/><br/></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var img_src = jQuery("#random_image").find("img").attr("src");
    var random_img_name = "image_"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) + ".jpg";
    var new_img_src = img_src.replace("RANDOM_IMAGE_NAME", random_img_name); 
    jQuery("#random_image").find("img").attr("src",new_img_src);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Anil, thank you for your help.
I'm a programmer, but the Magento environment is new to me.

This part of the code that I put as an example, is part of the content that creates my homepage.

This would be the block name?

[<div class="grid-container page-banners">]

This php code that you have created a page that I save in any folder on my server?

Comment: are you using jQuery at homepage OR can you show the web link ?

Comment: Is it possible to do that?
[banners/image_".rand(1,5).".jpg"]

www.bottonshirt.com.br

Comment: is an image that is in the middle of the page, where it appears a blond girl : )

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: See, I added the code but did not load the page properly.
www.bottonshirt.com.br

Comment: have you added `id="random_image"` to the DIV ? I cant find it

Comment: No I'm sorry.

Now it worked, thank you !!

Can I use this same feature to change other images? As the picture Button and mug?

In this particular case add twice this block javascript?

Comment: Yes, just change IDs of `DIV` and `javascript` accordingly. : )

Comment: Hi Anil, okay? 
Remember the code to load a random image?
  I had not seen, but it affected the product page.

I had to leave, could you help me?

Thank you very much!